# How to save a clicked link's data-attribute for use with other functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm new to jQuery and JS and am trying to use a chosen "subject" matter when the user chooses from a list of buttons. Using this subject, data-attribute value, is beyond me when using the data in and out of scope.

1. What are the pros and con's of saving data to the window object?
2. Best or better ways to do it...
3. What are the pro's and con's of saving to and retrieving with an input field?
4. Are there better ways that I don't know about?

Comment: Are you trying to save this stuff after a page reload or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll call the link `#link` with a data attribute `foo`

```
var data;
//this function is called when the link is clicked - making sure the var is *only*
created for clicked links
$('#link').click(function() {
  data = $(this).data('foo');
  //code to do whatever you want it to do
})
```

So now we have, for this page, a variable `data` with the value of `foo` stored inside it. Any functions can now use the data stored in this variable, and you could store it somewhere for later use using either `localStorage` or a cookie.

If you use the jQuery cookie plugin [on GitHub](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), you can simply call the function and set a cookie with it like this:

```
$.cookie('name','value');
```

so in this instance:

```
$.cookie('foo',data);
```

Alternatively, modern browsers can use localStorage, which doesn't require any plugins but may be a bit limited in IE and older versions of Firefox etc.

Usage for localStorage would be:

```
localStorage.foo = data; //localStorage.foo can be anything you want -- localStorage.bar, etc
```

Next time you want to reference it, you simply pull it into your JavaScript/jQuery using either itself or setting it to a var:

```
if(localStorage.foo == "this") { //do something }
```

or

```
var foo = localStorage.foo;
if(foo == "this") { //do something}
```

To answer your question more directly:

1) Browser compatibility. This will always be your biggest enemy, especially if you know you have to deal with older browsers like IE8. Pros - it's incredibly easy to do and flows well with JavaScript/jQuery

2) Always provide a fallback. In this case using a cookie will prevent you from losing functionality in older browsers.

3) Not sure I understand what you're asking there.

4) Probably. There's always something newer and bigger and better coming out. These are the two methods I currently use in my sites, and I haven't had any *major* issues yet.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to teach a bit. I just re-tried your recommendations and the reason I asked this is because I had already tried the "property method" of making variables without success. So I was confused... Thanks again.